# Unable to Launch/Open QGIS

Tags: qgis, installation, windows-10

Every time I install the QGIS version 3.12/3.16 64 bit, it is installed but unable to launch the application.

Comment: What operating system do you use? How did you install qgis?

Comment: Have you made sure, you picked the right version for your system (e.g. 32/64 bit)? And have you tried to start it with(out) Grass - usually QGIS pops up twice if you search for it on windows. Since 3.16 is the latest long term release it should be fairly stable.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: is it blocked by your anti-virus

Comment: see https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/32247